# Setting an image to be the first image the page renders in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using React for a project and I'm trying to set a desired image to be the first image a root component loads, right now the first image being loaded is the logo from navbar component that's also a part of the root page component.

I've looked online for a solution but didn't find any, is there any way to do that in React? something like delaying the rendering of all other images except one.

The reason that I want to achieve this is to share the production webpage in an app, and the app takes the first image loaded as the default cover image for the shared link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps generally use images declared in a [`meta`](https://css-tricks.com/essential-meta-tags-social-media/) tag as the preview. You should check which meta tag the other site uses, grabbing the "first" image is likely just a fallback for a missing `meta` tag

Comment: Yes, og:image meta tags are what I'm looking for, just didn't know that was an option before, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Facebook has a nice tool for meta debugging that may come in handy https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 0):

```js
const {complete} = document.getElementById("myImg") // select image. You can  use ref here as well.

if (complete) {/*do your stuff, eg setState({displayContent: true})*/}
```